# Java - Return two dimensional array value from get method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to return all values of 2D array. How I can return it if I use get method with String type?
And how if I want to  make the output like table (one line per row) with no brackets and comma?

```
public class Data {
private final String[][] table;
public Data(){
    table = new String[][] {{"ID", "NAME"},
                            {"101", "A"},
                            {"102", "B"},
                            {"103", "C"},
                            {"104", "D"},
                            {"105", "E"}};
}

public String[][] get(){
    return table;
}

public void displayMessage(){
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(get()));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your get method it would return type String[][]. So to use that method just call a variable of type String[][] and reference to your get method:

```
String[][] newStringArray; // unreferenced (aka null)
Data dataObj = new Data();
newStringArray = dataObj.get();
```

Comment: I want to make the output like table (one line per row) with no brackets and comma. Not to call it

Comment: @MarkMartin You could change the implementation of your get() method and iterate through your table using a for loop to display each row

Comment: @AndrewSo, it can't be printed well by using return type method?

Comment: @MarkMartin I do not believe it can be. Using the 'return' type basically passes a copy of the object or variable in question to whatever is calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void displayMessage(){
    for (String[] name : this.table){
        System.out.println(name[0] + " " + name[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I put the get method?